# Pyspark apply replace

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, replace, apply

I have a CSV file with many columns and I am trying to remove all of the double-quotes (") in the dataframe I created from the CSV.

Currently my code is as follows

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

def removeDoubleQuotes(x):
   return x.replace('"', '')

newDf = df.apply(removeDoubleQuotes, axis=1)
```

But when I run this code, the output remains the same (still has double-quotes)

Just to test the apply function, I appended a string to the end of each value and it worked. So, I am unsure why replace isn't working. (Checking the types of each element, they are all strings).

I've also tested on a single cell in the dataframe and the removeDoubleQuotes function also works.

Perhaps I am misusing apply?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyspark regexp_replace funtion.
Example :-

```
>>> df=spark.read.format("csv").option('header','True').option('inferSchema', 'True').option("delimiter", '|').load("/Path to/sample1.csv")
>>> df.show()
+--------+--------------------+--------+------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+-----+----+
| OrderID|             Product|Quantity| Price|          OrderDate|      StoreAddres|           City|State|Month|Hour|
+--------+--------------------+--------+------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+-----+----+
|295665.0|  Macbook Pro Laptop|     1.0|1700.0|2019-12-30 00:01:00|136 Church St, Ne|New " York City|  123| 12.0| 0.0|
|295666.0|  LG Washing Machine|     1.0| 600.0|2019-12-29 07:03:00|   562 2nd St, Ne|New York " City|   NY| 12.0| 7.0|
|295667.0|USB-C Charging Cable|     1.0| 11.95|2019-12-12 18:21:00| 277 Main St, New|  New York City|   NY| 12.0|18.0|
+--------+--------------------+--------+------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------+-----+-----+----+

>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df.withColumn('City', regexp_replace('City', '\"', '')).show()
+--------+--------------------+--------+------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+----+
| OrderID|             Product|Quantity| Price|          OrderDate|      StoreAddres|          City|State|Month|Hour|
+--------+--------------------+--------+------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+----+
|295665.0|  Macbook Pro Laptop|     1.0|1700.0|2019-12-30 00:01:00|136 Church St, Ne|New  York City|  123| 12.0| 0.0|
|295666.0|  LG Washing Machine|     1.0| 600.0|2019-12-29 07:03:00|   562 2nd St, Ne|New York  City|   NY| 12.0| 7.0|
|295667.0|USB-C Charging Cable|     1.0| 11.95|2019-12-12 18:21:00| 277 Main St, New| New York City|   NY| 12.0|18.0|
+--------+--------------------+--------+------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----+-----+----+
```

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for your answer! The reason I am using Apply though is so that it is done on the whole dataframe and not just a column. I don't want to iterate over all the columns because there are a lot